# Update SharePoint document library item hyperlink field using using Microsoft Graph in C#

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to update a SharePoint document library item's hyperlink field using Microsoft Graph in C#.

I'm using [Microsoft.Graph 4.10.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/4.10.0) to update the hyperlink in SharePoint. This is the code I have tried which give me an `Invalid request` error.

```
var fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"OriginalImageLink", new Dictionary<string, string>{{"https://example.com/img1.jpg", "https://example.com/img1.jpg"}}}
    }
};

await GraphClient.Sites["siteId"].Lists["listId"].Items["listItemId"].Fields.Request().UpdateAsync(fieldValueSet);
```

I can update a text field in SharePoint which works fine:

```
var fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"Comment", "This is my comment"}
    }
};
```

I can also update the hyperlink using HTTP:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "OriginalImageLink": {"Url": "https://example.com/img1.jpg", "Description": "https://example.com/img1.jpg"}
}
```

Conclusion: I can't update a SharePoint hyperlink field using C#. But I can update a text field in SharePoint and I can update the hyperlink using HTTP.

How do I update the SharePoint hyperlink field using C#?

**Update:**

This feature is currently not supported. [Upvote this feature](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-to-update-of-sharepoint-listitem-with-hyperlink-field/idi-p/3021504#M506)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify `Url` and `Description` fields in `fieldValueSet`?

```
var fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "OriginalImageLink", new Dictionary<string, string> 
            { 
                { "Url" , "https://example.com/img1.jpg" },
                { "Description", "https://example.com/img1.jpg"}
            } 
        }
    }
};

await GraphClient.Sites["siteId"].Lists["listId"].Items["listItemId"].Fields
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(fieldValueSet);
```

Update:

According to this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/645640/how-to-update-sharepoint-list-item-hyperlink-colum.html) the update of sharepoint listitem with hyperlink field is not supported.

Comment: I have tried that and got 'Invalid request' error.

Comment: @Høgsdal Please see the latest update in my answer